# Possible bug with Testing Notebook & messages x::y where x has an OwnValue

Tags: notebooks, message-coding, user-interface, testing-and-verification

I think this should be considered a bug (or at least an inconvenience) and should be reported:

Say you have some code generating the `$RecursionLimit::reclim2` message (on purpose). E.g.

```
z = z[0];
z
```

Create a new testing notebook and test case, put this in the Input, `Hold[z[0]]` in the Expected Output and then shift enter on the Input.

You get a Message Failure (orange) and the section Actual Messages pops up, erroneously reporting:

```
 {1024::reclim2, 1024::reclim2}
```

[image]

when it should say `{$RecursionLimit::reclim2, $RecursionLimit::reclim2}`. Therefore you can't as usually copy the messages list, hit Add Messages and paste them there, but have to reverse-engineer what the unevaluated LHS of this message name is.

What do you think?

Comment: Do you have the [Suggestions Bar turned on](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/75284#75284)?  (Turn it off. Mine is off, and I cannot reproduce your results.)

Comment: No, it's off. This is 10.4 x64 Windows.

Comment: As I said, I cannot reproduce the problem ("10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"): http://i.stack.imgur.com/BsiQM.png

Comment: @MichaelE2 The problem appears *only* in a Testing Notebook (when it tells you about messages that where generated), not in a normal input cell, can you try that?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I get the error.  I misinterpreted "Testing Notebook" in the title as equivalent to "testing a notebook". I also tend to read the body of the question and not pay much attention to the title. I haven't used "Testing Notebook" much and didn't recognize the styling. I guess I wasn't the only one.  -- To answer your original question: Yes, I think it's a bug.